# Lot of unwanted space above html table in IE browser

Tags: html, removing-whitespace

I have the below code :
[image]
   The table is rendered properly but there is a lot of unwanted space above the table. When I checked in chrome debugger, there are lot of white spaces added in the code. But the actual code does not have it. I did not copy and paste the code from anywhere. Please can anyone guide how to fix this issue. [image]

Comment: Looks like printOtherDocuments adds a lot of whitespace. Without knowing what it does we can't help you

Comment: Please add the code for the `printOtherDocuments()` method.

Comment: Thanks Lumio. I did not realise the spaces were coming from printOtherDocuments  method. After you mentioned in the comment I took a look at that method and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were lot of &nbsp added in printOtherDocuments() method which I dint notice earlier. After removing those the issue was fixed.